# Is this Haskell function recalculating needlessly?

Tags: haskell

I want to compute values in an infinite grid of integers, where each square contains an integer from 0 to 3.  I designed a function that increments a square: it adds one to the value of that square, but if the square would then hold a 4, it sets the square to 0 and calls itself on the four adjacent squares.

```
type Board = (Int,Int) -> Int

setSquareTo :: Int -> (Int,Int) -> Board -> Board
setSquareTo n (x,y) b (z,w) | x == z && y == w = n
                            | otherwise        = b (z,w)

incSquare :: (Int,Int) -> Board -> Board
incSquare (x,y) b | b (x,y) == 3 = incSquare (x+1,y).incSquare (x,y+1).incSquare (x-1,y).incSquare (x,y-1).setSquareTo 0 (x,y) $ b
                  | otherwise    = setSquareTo (b (x,y) + 1) (x,y) b
```

Now, I think this is doing only the calculations it needs to when finding the value of **one** square in a board generated by incSquare.  However, it seems like finding the values of two adjacent squares one after the other wastes a lot of time doing the some of the same calculations in each case.  Is this true?

If so is there a way a simple way of improving performance? Would something like

```
type Board = IntMap (IntMap Int)
```

using the strict version of IntMap be better?  (How would I set every square to 0 initially in that case?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of thing I wrote [data-inttrie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-inttrie) for. It behaves just like a function from Int, except that it supports efficient single-point modifications through memoization.

You can initialize with any function f with `fmap f identity`, then use `overwrite` and `modify` to change it one value at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Using a function as `Board` type is not such a good idea since the functions get more and more complicated when more calls to `setSquareTo` are made. 
Then more and more space will be used to save this more and more complicated function. Also, when calling it with a value `(x, y)` for which `setSquareTo` hasn't been called for a long time, it takes a long time because the function first checks if the supplied parameter is one of the other coordinates.

So you should use `Map (Int, Int) Int` or your proposed `IntMap (IntMap Int)` instead as type for `Board` instead.

If you use `Map (Int, Int) Int`, you can use `findWithDefault (x, y) 0 b` instead of `b (x, y)` in this case to get 0 if this value doesn't yet exist in the map, so you don't have to initially set every value to 0 which isn't possible when you have an infinite board.